# is there a script to block outbound connection if vpn disconnects?

Tags: network

My vpn service drops from time to time and It reconnects again automatically but my real ip is exposed from the time is disconnects and reconnects which usually takes a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Some VPN providers have 'Internet kill switches' for their VPN that will cut your Internet connection in case of a disconnect so check yours.

There is a large number of 3d party applications that will disable the outbound traffic if VPN disconnect.

[VPN watcher](http://www.ugdsoft.com/products/vpnwatcher/)...and others.

I suggest you use one of those, since making a script would be like reinventing the wheel.

But if you have to here are the instructions how to.

[Creating a kill switch for the OSX VPN client](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20140423225754712)